# Can Rhythmbox scrobble tracks from an Internet radio stream?

Tags: rhythmbox

I'm mainly using Rhythmbox for listening to music, this includes radio streams. However I noticed that the radio tracks are not scrobbled to Last.fm.

Is there any way around this? I want my radio stations scrobbled as well, because I listen to them mostly.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, it is not possible to 'scrobble' tracks from an Internet radio stream with Rhythmbox.

When this question was posed as a bug report/feature request here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=376659 it was marked by the Rhythmbox developers as being something that ***won't be fixed*** due to the nature of Internet radio streams not providing the correct metadata to be able to determine the correct artist and title.

> If a user is playing a stream instead of a regular file, do not submit that stream/song.
>
> and also
>
> Do not try to guess info from the filename - if there are no tags, don't submit the file.
>
> The shoutcast metadata provided by most streams only includes a single
>   title string which cannot reliably be split into artist and song title
>   fields.